# Heights being displayed differently in iReport on different operating systems

Tags: ireport

If I create a Jasper report in iReport on Linux and open the same report in iReport on OS X the text within an element will not be displayed unless I increase the height of the encasing element. The same goes going from OS X to Windows.

iReport versions and Java versions are the same.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of different font metrics on different systems. If you use font extensions to specify the precise font that will be used, then this problem should go away.

Try using the DejaVu fonts which ship with iReport and JasperReports for your text element to confirm.